# ArcGIS Server logs for cached map services

Tags: arcgis-server, log

ArcGIS Server has a [log event](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/windows/map-service-log-codes.htm) for accessing dynamic map service (`Begin\End ExportMapImage` - code 10010).

Is there something similar for cached map services? Or is there any other way to determine how many times tiles have been served to end users? I noticed there should be a log message for `GetMapTile has started\completed` (code 10054) but I don't see any messages of this type in my server manager.